# ActiveStorage : Add photo's credit to an attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a model with "has_many_attached :photos"

I would like to add some informations to my attachments (but not for all) like :

```
- "author"
- "source_link"
- "licence"
- "licence_link"
```

What's the best way to do that ? I don't use any gem for upload, just ActiveStorage.

Comment: which gem you are using for file upload?

Comment: I use ActiveStorage without gem

Answer (score 1):

Your files to be uploaded will be the object of Specific kind of Attachments. For example in **paperclip** it will be `Paperclip::Attachment`

Moreover, This Attachment has a `options` as a hash where you can store extra information for your attachments by merging in it.

for example `User.last.photo.options.merge({data: 'value'})`

Comment: I don't use any gem for upload, just ActiveStorage

Comment: see your attachment object in console, find any field which stores the hash and merge your wanted data in it